# Android Studio: My layouts are all gone. What happened?

Tags: android, android-layout

I had several layouts for various size devices and at each orientation. Somehow, they've all disappeared and only the original layout shows again, no matter which device type or size or orientation I select in  Android Studio's renderer.

I've upgraded Android Studio. I've renamed the parent folder the source project and files were in. I've upgraded the sdk. Also, Although my app is not a Gradle project, I did *something* the IDE kept bugging me to do... I believe I moved something from AndroidManifest to build.gradle.

I don't know which step caused me to lose my layouts, as I didn't notice as I worked on other things.

Does anyone have any idea what I might have done that would cause my layouts to disappear?

Thanks.

Comment: Just restore them from your backup or source-control.

Comment: But that's the thing. I've copied all the layouts from my previous version to the layouts folder of my new version... and I've even just renamed my old version to the new version name and tried to work from that, but the newer layouts I created still do not appear.... only my very first "development" layout appears.

Answer (score 1):

They have not disappeared and you have not lost them![image]

Click on the drop down which I have circled (It probably says Android for you) and choose "Project" view which is what you were used to before the update.

Comment: My layout files are still there. The rendering engine is working. The problem is that the color layouts of various sizes had stopped working, no matter which target I selected to render. When I tried to import the old app version, which had no build.gradle file, the import failed (I just got a dialog box which said "Gradle: Download https://services.gradle.org/districutions/gradle" but it never got done. Still, after I used the Task Manager to quit Android Studio, when I reopened the newer version of the project, it had multiple renderings again. I do not understand what is happening.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but again, the answer is here ^

Comment: @qazimusab please don't add non-answer content to your questions. Thanks!